# Canvas background image is on top of second drawn image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onload

I have a background image set in my canvas; it's a map.

I then want to "draw" red pin images on various points on top of the map. Right now in Chrome, the first pin I have "drawn" with the context, is coming up underneath the background map.

I am not seeing this behavior with Firefox/IE.

My end game is that I want the pins to be interactive (onMouseOver/onClick/etc). Should I even be using a canvas element to do this?

See code below:

```
<canvas id="backgroundMapCanvas" width="990" height="691" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var context = document.getElementById("backgroundMapCanvas").getContext("2d");

    var bgImage = new Image();
    bgImage.src = "images/mapBackground.jpg";

    bgImage.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(bgImage, 10, 10);
    };

    var firstPin = new Image();
    firstPin.src = "images/redPin.png";

    firstPin.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(firstPin, 830, 420);
    };
</script>
```

Thanks,

V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading order is not guaranteed as it depends on the image's size, server etc. so you need to force correct order, and this can be done by tracking loading status for all images, and *then* draw the images in the order you intended:

- Share load handler
- Use a counter
- Draw when all images has loaded.

**Example:**

```
var bgImage = new Image();
var firstPin = new Image();
var count = 2;

bgImage.onload = loader;
firstPin.onload = loader;

bgImage.src = "images/mapBackground.jpg";
firstPin.src = "images/redPin.png";

function loader() {
    if (!--count) draw();   // draw when both has loaded
}

function draw() {
    context.drawImage(bgImage, 10, 10);
    context.drawImage(firstPin, 830, 420);
}
```

Comment: What if I simply want to make the background image static? Drawing order of all subsequent pins do not matter.

Comment: @azadvirat you could set the background image with CSS to the canvas element and just draw the pins using the context. Just note that if you plan to save out the canvas as an image later the CSS background won't be included.

Comment: Setting the main map image as the CSS background image while drawing pin images over the map seems to be working quite well. Thanks!